# How to get rest of the records after a certain limit with activerecord

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I got first 2 record out of 10 using following

```
News.all.order("published_at desc").limit(2)
```

How do i get rest of the 8 record?

Comment: If i did not use `.all` i got following error message  `NoMethodError: undefined method order for News:Class` (News is my model name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naturally, you skip those two and get the remaining 8

```
News.order("published_at desc").offset(2).limit(8)
```

(Tested with ActiveRecord 3.2.11)

Comment: this works for you? in my tests `skip` returns an internal arel object. This works for me: `News.order("published_at desc").offset(2).limit(8)`

Comment: Ah, sorry, in Mongoid it's `skip`. :) I extrapolated that to ActiveRecord

Comment: oh, I see. I was confused because `skip` is indeed a method, but not exposed by AR but by Arel. It's a pity because it's more declarative.